# Nonnegative integer solutions to $\sum_{j=1}^{8}x_j=24$ with $\sum_{j=1}^4x_j>\sum_{j=5}^8x_j$ stars and bars

Tags: combinatorics

I need to find the nonnegative integer solutions to $\sum_{j=1}^{8}x_j=24$ with the constrains$\sum_{j=1}^4x_j>\sum_{j=5}^8x_j$. I have no idea how to use stars and bars for such constraints.

I thought about finding the number of cases $p$ for which $\sum_{j=1}^4x_j=\sum_{j=5}^8x_j$, and then by symmetry the answer would be $(\binom{31}{24}-p)/2$, but this seems like a poor approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think it a poor approach at all: it’s exactly the approach that I would use. It immediately yields the answer,

$$\frac12\left(\binom{31}{24}-\binom{15}{12}^2\right)=1,211,275\;.$$

The calculation is even quite manageable by hand if you rewrite it as

$$\frac12\left(\binom{31}7-\binom{15}3^2\right)\;.\tag{1}$$

An alternative is to sum over the possible values of $\sum_{j=1}^4x_j$:

$$\sum_{s=0}^{11}\binom{s+3}3\binom{27-s}{3}\;,$$

but this ultimately reduces to $(1)$.

Comment: Ah, silly me, I forgot there's only one case in which the sums are equal since we know the total sum is $24$... Thanks!

Comment: @combinarcotics: You’re welcome!